# delete my duplicate?

Tags: support

My question https://askubuntu.com/questions/148114/easy-terminal-controllable-media-player is receiving hate after years after it was marked a duplicate. Its close to being deleted. Should it be deleted if its moderation policy? I agree that the question does little good.

Also what about the notion that duplicates increase the findability of questions? Is it unhelpful here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I believe your question should stay as a signpost for people who come here by search machines.

I just did a quick search with Google for

```
terminal media player
```

(which I believe is what people may search if they look for a command line solution) to find the duplicate question ([Command line audio players](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44443/command-line-audio-players)) on range 3 **only** because the Google robots search for titles of linked questions on the side bar too. It is where your question shows up.

If your question was deleted we then may not be directed so easily to the appropriate helpful question on Ask Ubuntu by a search with terms as above.

So I do vote **against** deleting you question, and I actually do not really understand why it had to be downvoted.

Comment: So its the action of many overzealous persons? Got it.